# Help with mathematic notation

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, machine-learning

I am looking at a mathematical expression and could use some help in understanding these notations and also If you could please provide a reference where I could read more about these notations so that I can learn this order of operation and learn how to solve similar problems on my own.
This is a computer algorithm for machine learning (in this particular instance):

> $\|x\|_1$ is solved by:
>   $$x_1 = \arg\min \|x\|_1 \text{ s.t. } y = Ax$$

I have never seen the large "||" symbols before, so It would be awesome if someone could tell me what they are called, how they work, and where I can get more details on its function.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Answer (score 1):

They are called [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)).

$$\|x\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|$$

The problem that you mentioned can be solved by a linear program.

Comment: I think the absolute sign $|\cdot|$ around $x_i$ is missing.  Interestingly, the linked Wiki article shows $$\left\|{\boldsymbol {x}}\right\|_{1}:=\sum _{i=1}^{n}\left|x_{i}\right|$$ under the section **Taxicab norm or Manhattan norm**.

Comment: you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$\lVert \cdot \rVert_1$ is called the *1-norm*.  For a vector $x \in F^n$, where $F$ is a field, the 1-norm of $x$ is defined as $$\|x\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here, $x$ is a vector, presumably in $\mathbb{R}^n$, meaning you can write it as a $1\times n$ column matrix, $\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{bmatrix}$. The norm $||x||_p = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p\right)^{1/p}$. When $p=1$, it is the sum of the absolute values of the components, $$||x||_1 = |x_1|+|x_2|+\dots+|x_n|$$

The problem given here is an optimization problem, specifically a convex optimization problem called [$\ell_1$ minimization](http://www.ens-lyon.fr/DI/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/lecture-3-3-l1dual.pdf).